# How do I dynamically change the colour of my button using the value of a variable in a Javascript Object?

Tags: html, css, angular

My html creates a table with buttons on which are currently coloured green.

**html**

```
      <tr *ngFor="let d of dataLinkResult;">
        <td>
          <a [routerLink]="['/details', d.leftDatabase, d.leftCollection,d.leftId ]">
            <span *ngIf="d.leftId" class="btn {{d.leftId}} table-button text-left" data-toggle="tooltip"
              title="Database: {{d.leftDatabase}}, Collection: {{d.leftCollection}}">{{d.leftName}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="!d.leftId" class="btn table-button text-left" id="leftNode">[NULL]</span>
          </a>
          <br>
          <i style="color:black">Database: {{d.leftDatabase}}, Collection: {{d.leftCollection}}</i>
        </td>
        <td class="relationship">{{d.relationshipDescription}}</td>
        <td>
          <a [routerLink]="['/details', d.rightDatabase, d.rightCollection,d.rightId ]">
            <span *ngIf="d.rightId" class="btn {{d.rightId}} table-button text-left" data-toggle="tooltip"
              title="Database: {{d.rightDatabase}}, Collection {{d.rightCollection}}">{{d.rightName}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="!d.rightId" class="btn table-button text-left" id="rightNode">[NULL]</span>
          </a>
          <br>
          <i style="color:black">Database: {{d.rightDatabase}}, Collection: {{d.rightCollection}}</i>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Each d of the data link result looks like so:

```
{id: "5dd41cb989a1db3edcdafbed",
leftDatabase: "Random",
leftCollection: "lorems",
leftId: "5dd41cb289a1db3edcdafa14",
leftName: "nihil",
leftColour: "#32a89e",
rightDatabase: "Commerce",
rightCollection: "products",
rightId: "5dd41cb289a1db3edcdaf990",
rightName: "Unbranded Metal Soap",
rightColour: "#a88b32"}
```

and finally my **css** which I want to change according to whatever is in d.leftColour or d.rightColour

```
.table-button {
background-color: chartreuse;
}
```

So in this case - I would want the element with the id of leftNode to have the colour #32a89e, and the element with the id of rightNode to have the colour #a88b32.

But this will potenitally change for each d of dataLinkResult - so I need to ensure the colour is updated dynamically.

I'd prefer  **not to use JQuery**  for this if possible.

Comment: *ngIf not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ngStyle`,

For left button,

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':d.leftColour}"
```

For right button,

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':d.rightColour}"
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1l1ztr

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle attribute as follows and check the data is equal as you check the properties of 'd'

```
[ngStyle]="d.data=='something'?{'background-color':'green'} : {'background-color': 'white'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
document.getElementById('leftNode').style['background-color'] = d.leftColour;
document.getElementById('rightNode').style['background-color'] = d.rightColour;
```

This way you're not using JQuery.

Comment: This is plain JS :). Angular provides dynamic styling using `ngStyle` and `ngClass`. You can learn them from here [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle), [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)